# How should I stack up optical flow along axes to pass it to a neural network

Tags: computer-vision

I have extracted the optical flow along x and y axes. I want to pass them into a ConvNet. The thing I cannot understand is whether these should be two different input channels or should I combine them in some way, like stacking them, adding them or averaging them

Paper- [Two-Stream Convolutional Networks
for Action Recognition in Videos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2199.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Stack them so that it is an input with two channels. This is the standard approach.

Comment: Do you mean the optical flow images will have 6 channels, 3 for each ?

Comment: No, one channel is for the $x$ component of the flow, one channel is for the $y$ component of the flow. There are two channels in total.